# ¿como crear ciclo que permita insertar horas con diferencias de cada 15 minutos en base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, fullcalendar

estoy usando full calendar y php para llenarlo de eventos, recivo de un formulario que hice una una fecha y una hora de inicio y otra de fin, lo que quiero hacer es programarlo de forma que si coloco como hora inicial 8:00 am y hora final 1:00 pm por ejemplo me haga creo que 20 insert a la base de datos, con la misma informacion pero con diferencia de 15 minutos en la hora el primero seria de 8 a 8:15 y el segundo de 8:15 a 8:30 y asi sucesivamente. pero no lo logro,si es mi codigo

```
 public function create_event(Request $request){
    $input= $request->all();
    $minutosA=15;
    $segundosInicio=strtotime($input["hora_inicio"]);
    $segundos_añadir=$minutosA*60;
    $horaFin=date("H:i",$segundosInicio+$segundos_añadir);
    $horaInicio=$input["hora_inicio"];
    $input["idEspecialista"]="2";
    $input["descripcion"]="este es un evento de prueba";
    $input["color"]="#FD1C02";
    $input["inicio"]=$input["inicio"]." ".$horaInicio;
    $input["fin"]=$input["fin"]." ".$input["hora_fin"];
    calendar::create($input);
    return redirect()->route('calendar');
}
```

si alguien sabe como deberia programar el ciclo seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para manipular fechas y horas en Laravel es recomendable usar `Carbon`, tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$horaInicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $input["hora_inicio"]);

for ( $i=0;$i<20;$i++ )
{
    $horaFin = $horaInicio -> addMinutes(15);

    $input["idEspecialista"] = "2";
    $input["descripcion"]    = "este es un evento de prueba";
    $input["color"]          = "#FD1C02";
    $input["inicio"]         = $horaInicio;
    $input["fin"]            = $hora_fin;
    calendar::create($input);
    return redirect()->route('calendar');

    $horaInicio = $horaFin;
}
```